# How to train a neural net with multiple timeseries?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am trying to train a `feedforwardnet` that takes in a `timeseries` input predicts from it a `timeseries` output.

I have an Input cell that is 20 X 961, where each cell is a vector with two elements (two variables u1 and u2).

And an Output cell that is also 20 X 961, where each cell is a vector with two elements (two variables x1 and x2).

Each column corresponds to one 'run' of the experiment, so I have 961 different experiment results to train the net with.
Whenever I try the code:

```
[net,tr] = train(net, Input', Output');
```

It throws me some error such as wrong numInputs or wrong numOutputs. Honestly I don't really know enough about matlab neural nets to know what is wrong or even if feedforward net is the sort of the net I am looking for. Could you give me guidance? Thank you so much!

A smaller version of the data taken from two runs of the experiments is as follows;

```
Input = {
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
[0,1],  [0,2]
}

Output = {
[0,0],  [0,0]
[0,9.93150000000000],   [0,11.9180000000000]
[0,9.99990000000000],   [0,12]
[0,9.99900000000000],   [0,11.9980000000000]
[0,9.98920000000000],   [0,11.9950000000000]
[0,9.99920000000000],   [0,11.9990000000000]
[0,10.0060000000000],   [0,12.0070000000000]
[0,9.99930000000000],   [0,11.9980000000000]
[0,10.0010000000000],   [0,12.0020000000000]
[0,10.0010000000000],   [0,11.9970000000000]
[0,9.99970000000000],   [0,12]
[0,9.99900000000000],   [0,11.9980000000000]
[0,9.99680000000000],   [0,11.9990000000000]
[0,9.99910000000000],   [0,11.9990000000000]
[0,10.0040000000000],   [0,12.0060000000000]
[0,10.0050000000000],   [0,11.9990000000000]
[0,9.99840000000000],   [0,11.9990000000000]
[0,9.99900000000000],   [0,11.9990000000000]
[0,10.0060000000000],   [0,12.0090000000000]
[0,10.0030000000000],   [0,11.9980000000000]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this layrecnet present in MATLAB. For your usecase.
**layrecnet** : Layer recurrent neural networks are similar to feedforward networks, except that each layer has a recurrent connection with a tap delay associated with it. This allows the network to have an infinite dynamic response to time series input data.
**preparets** : Prepare input and target time series data for network simulation or training
Refer to this example for better understanding :

```
[X,T] = simpleseries_dataset;
net = layrecnet(1:2,10);
[Xs,Xi,Ai,Ts] = preparets(net,X,T);
net = train(net,Xs,Ts,Xi,Ai);
view(net)
Y = net(Xs,Xi,Ai);
perf = perform(net,Y,Ts)
```

Comment: Okay! I will try this. Thank you!